# JavaScript function default parameter is not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, function, ecmascript-6

As per ES6, we can provide the default value of parameters (here I provide value 0 to the second parameter). Now, if I am providing values of `20` & `null` in function, as per ES6, it should take now values as 20 & 0 so alert must ping `20`, but it is alerting `NaN`. Can someone help me out?

```js
function alpha(a, b = '0') {
  return (a != null ? '$' + (parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b)) : "");
}

alert(alpha(20, null)); //output is NaN
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters

Comment: That documentation you link to *explicitly* mentions that `null` and other *falsey* values are ***not*** replaced…

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Now, if I am providing values of 20 & null in function, as per ES6, it should take now values as 20 & 0

Nope. :-) `null` isn't replaced by the default. The only value replaced by the default is `undefined` (whether you give it explicitly, or just leave off that parameter).

So:

```js
function alpha(a, b = '0') {
  return (a != null ? '$' + (parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b)) : "");
}

console.log(alpha(20));            // Gets default
console.log(alpha(20, undefined)); // Gets default
console.log(alpha(20, null));      // Does not get default
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `null` in parameter `b` so null is assigned to `b`. To get the default value work you should omit the second parameter in your function.

```js
function alpha(a, b ='0'){
 return (a!=null ?  '$' + (parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b)) :  ""); 
}

alert(alpha(20));
```